# REACT JS after deploy and build pages don't open

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, build, mern

im student, and im still learning, but i need help.

i really need help its a project

when i have deployed system and run by build the initial page works, but all the redirects not.

page is up if you need to see:
http://calces.com.br/

on console show this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' 2.283742ca.chunk.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' main.0f14d6e0.chunk.js:1

after some search i tryied change server information:

```
const root = require('path').join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')
app.use(express.static(root));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
})
```

i have changed .htaccess, i have tryied these two options:

```
Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

here my routes, i have tryied change to HashRouter, but nothing...

```
<BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                {/*Rota Cliente*/}
                <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
                <Route path="/produtos/:idProduto" exact component={ProdutoDetails} />
                <Route render={() => <h1>Not Found Page</h1>} />
                
                {/*Rota Admin*/}
                <Route path="/admin/login" exact component={Login} />
                <Route path="/admin" exact component={Dashboard} />

                <Route path="/admin/itens" component={Itens} />
                <Route path="/admin/itens/cadastrar" exact component={ItemCadastrar} />
                <Route path="/admin/itens/editar/:idItem" exact component={ItemEditar} />

                <PrivateRoute path="/admin/servicos" exact component={Servicos} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/admin/servicos/cadastrar" exact component={ServicoCadastrar} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/admin/servicos/editar/:idServico" exact component={ServicoEditar} />
           </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

package.json(i have tryied to put "http://calces.com.br/" in homepage, but because the routes they just give me not found):

```
{
  
  "name": "client",
  "homepage":".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true, 
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.10.8",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.21.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "mui-datatables": "^3.7.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dnd": "^14.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL:'http://localhost:5000'
})

export default api;
```

Server Routes:

```
routes.get('/', Usuario.index);

// Rotas de Usuário
routes.post('/api/usuarios', Usuario.create);
routes.get('/api/usuarios', Usuario.index);
routes.get('/api/usuarios.details/:_id', Usuario.details);
routes.delete('/api/usuarios/:_id', Usuario.delete);
routes.put('/api/usuarios', Usuario.update);
routes.post('/api/usuarios/login', Usuario.login);
routes.get('/api/usuarios/checktoken', Usuario.checkToken);
routes.get('/api/usuarios/destroytoken', Usuario.destroyToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

The one reason I can think of is your backend and frontend might have same API endpoint. Let's say you go a page `http://example.com/user` and your server also has the same route, then the server route will be called instead of the client/frontend route.

Try prefixing `/api` to every endpoint. For the above example -

Client route - `/user` 
Server route - `/api/user`

Comment: im using axios to create baseURL:( i have updated code in question^^)
after your comment i have tryied change from localhost to domain, and from domain to localhost but same error...
and server route have all api/...(updated^)

Comment: I just remembered, that one time I was having trouble with routing with BrowserRouter so I switched to hashRouter and everything worked like charm !! Try this once.